# How can I get a .asc file to load into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, ascii

I got some files from an ag plane that are in ASCII format. I cannot seem to be able to get them to load into QGIS without the

[image: Error When Loading .asc file]

This is a link to the file I am trying to use.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7IZBVWB4R68Q1dBNlJaaUFUeDQ/view?usp=sharing

I was wondering if it was a problem with the file itself or is there an easy (or hard) solution to getting QGIS to read the file correctly?

Comment: this is highly customized data, not a standard geographic data format. Are the second and third (or fourth) columns coordinates (latitude, longitude)? They are not labeled as such. Even that seems unlikely, unless you are flying in the Mediterranean Sea or Kenya. What are you wanting to map with this data?

Comment: Definitely an issues with the file. There is a large amount of  information that a parser just cannot deal with. You have special characters along with repeated headers and complete changes in the data format. You need to modify the file so it has a header at the beginning of the file and then consistent columns that correspond to the columns. Each column, including the header should be separated with a comma.

Comment: With the dataset you provided, you are better of with a XYZ raster, or import as points using delimited text. Both require that the coordinates are found in every line of the text file.

Comment: I guess that data comes from some aeroplane that is spraying herbisides of something like that. Location is perhaps recorded at each "Mark". Locations for the application rate records should be interpreted by the timestamps between two marks. It is for sure doable but not as simple as "Load .asc into QGIS". If you know the flight operator you may ask if data are available in other formats or if they can give you an access to the data logger software that has written the ascii file out. It probably can also read and interpret it.

Comment: File extensions are not sacred! The only geographic data in the file are the mark positions. The rest seem to be spray data as user30184 says. The marks could possibly be either waypoints (giving a route along which spraying is done) or field identifiers (isolated points around which the plane sprays).  Therefore, your knowledge of the data is essential to determine how to handle it correctly. You need to write a simple routine to parse the file. You could create a table with fields mark, lon, lat and maybe flight time and mean application rate (for example). You can then import it into QGIS.